# How to add image to loop from adv custom fields and custom post type

Tags: image, custom-post-type

```
 <?php 
          // the query
          $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'features', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>

            <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>

              <!-- the loop -->
              <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

               <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>">

              <?php endwhile; ?>
              <!-- end of the loop -->   
              <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>            
          <?php else : ?>
              <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I have a problem with adding image to loop.
I create an custom image field assigned to custom post type "features" and I want to add this image field to loop.
This way is bad becouse in console in src="" is:

http://localhost/konkursy/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/smartphone_samsung.png, http://localhost/konkursy/konkursy_internetowe/caruzela-1/smartphone_samsung/, balbla, 1, sad, asd, smartphone_samsung, inherit, 56, 2019-01-02 10:56:12, 2019-01-02 12:06:21, 0, image/png, image, png, http://localhost/konkursy/wp-includes/images/media/default.png, 200, 150, Array">

I don't know how to do this with array becouse this field is assigned to post type not to template page

```
<?php 
$image = get_field('image');
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
```

This way is not working

Maybe someone who wants to help me can help this: 
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

In adv custom field options you can change array to URL;

or second option: add array to loop not to WP_Query like (like I so far)